# Is there any solution for "Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options)" error?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I have a problem using firebase with expo. I added the config and tried to add some content to Auth firebase.

I added my firebase.js file like this:

[image]

I wanted to make a function in my LogIn.js file like this:

[image]

handleRegister is the function that I use for onPress function of Register button

After all this I get the following:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry for posting this bad...

Comment: Hello, this issue was relatively simpler but its best to post code as text so it is easier for us to edit.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `getAuth()` directly in your components, there is no surety that Firebase was initialized in `firebase.js`. Instead you should always ensure `initializeApp()` is called before using any Firebase services. Here, you can import the `auth` instance created in `firebase.js` as shown below:

```
// firebase.js

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// add export 
export const auth = getAuth();
export const analytics = getAnalytics();
```

```
// Login.js


import { auth } from '../path/to/firebase.js' // <-- replace with correct path


// Remove the following
// const auth = getAuth();


// use imported 'auth'
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
```